# Need help with mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1241

So I am trying to do a somewhat complex query and am having trouble. I have structured it like this as it seems to be the most logical:

```
SELECT (intake.id, s_matters.id, s_calls.cid, s_events.id) AS id, 
      (intake.name, s_matters.casename, s_calls.name, s_events.subject) AS title 
 FROM intake, s_matters, s_calls, s_events 
WHERE title LIKE '%mi%'
```

That returns:

> Error Code : 1241
>   Operand should contain 1 column(s)

So I know it has something to do with the bracket structure, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Is there a `title` column in all of the four tables?  If not, which table is it from?  But your query is also a cartesian product--you need join criteria

Comment: Could you provide an example of your desired output?

Comment: reply from below: I am trying to join all the IDs from the different tables into one column titled "id" and join all the names in another column titled "title", in which the results would have "mi" somewhere in the "title" column. This is really just the first step, I also need a column that has the table name the row came from, so I know what type of data is in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that what is required would best be returned by the following:

```
SELECT id, name title, 'intake' table 
FROM intake WHERE name LIKE '%mi%'  
UNION ALL
SELECT id, casename title, 's_matters' table 
FROM s_matters WHERE casename LIKE '%mi%'  
UNION ALL
SELECT cid AS id, name title, 's_calls' table 
FROM s_calls WHERE name LIKE '%mi%'  
UNION ALL
SELECT id, subject title, 's_events' table 
FROM s_events WHERE subject LIKE '%mi%'
```

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table 
FROM intake WHERE name LIKE '%mi%'  
UNION ALL
SELECT id, casename tit' at line 1

Comment: Actually this was perfect, it just didn't like the virtual column being named "table"... changed to "type" and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An alias can only refer to one column. If the alias is intended for the last column in each list, do this:

```
SELECT intake.id, s_matters.id, s_calls.cid, s_events.id AS id, intake.name, 
    s_matters.casename, s_calls.name, s_events.subject AS title 
FROM intake, s_matters, s_calls, s_events 
WHERE title LIKE '%mi%'
```

Also, you are missing `ON` clauses from your joins. What is the query trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear what you are trying to do

SELECT concat(intake.id, s_matters.id, s_calls.cid, s_events.id) AS id, concat(intake.name, s_matters.casename, s_calls.name, s_events.subject) AS title FROM intake, s_matters, s_calls, s_events WHERE title LIKE '%mi%

May be what you intended. And as redfilter points out you your joins are missing ON clauses.

Comment: I am trying to join all the IDs from the different tables into one column titled "id" and join all the names in another column titled "title", in which the results would have "mi" somewhere in the "title" column.

Comment: Try the concat() function, it joins strings into one string which can then be referenced as a single field. You will need to specify how the tables should be joined though. Eg Where intake.id=s_matters.id etc.